# Pandas - find max number of taxi stops before back to depot

Tags: python, pandas

I've a pandas dataframe as below:

```
driver_id | trip_id | pickup_from | drop_off_to | date
    1     |    3    |     stop 1  | city1       |  2018-02-04
    1     |    7    |     city 2  | city3       |  2018-02-04
    1     |    4    |     city 4  | stop1       |  2018-02-04
    2     |    8    |     stop 1  | city7       |  2018-02-06
    2     |    9    |     city 8  | stop1       |  2018-02-06   
    2     |    12   |     stop 1  | city5       |  2018-02-07
    2     |    10   |     city 3  | city1       |  2018-02-07
    2     |    1    |     city 4  | city7       |  2018-02-07
    2     |    6    |     city 2  | stop1       |  2018-02-07
```

I want to calculate the longest trip for each driver between stop 1 in the (pick_from) column and stop 1 in the (drop_off_to) column. i.e: for driver 1 if he started from stop 1 and went to city 1 then city 2 then city 3 then city 4 and then back to stop 1. so the max number of trips should be the number of cities he visited = 4 cities.
For driver 2 he started from stop 1 and then went to city 7 and city 8 before he goes back to stop 1 so he visited 2 cities. Then he started from stop 1 again and visited city 5, city 3, city 1, city 4, city 7 and city 2 before he goes back to stop 1 then total number of cities he worked in is 6 cities. So for driver 2 the max number of cities he visited = 6. The date doesn't matter in our calculation.
How can I do this using Pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the following function computing the longest trip
for a driver:

```
def maxTrip(grp):
    trip = pd.DataFrame({'city': grp[['pickup_from', 'drop_off_to']]
        .values.reshape(1, -1).squeeze()})
    return trip.groupby(trip.city.str.match('stop').cumsum())\
        .apply(lambda grp2: grp2.drop_duplicates().city.size).max() - 1
```

Then apply it:

```
result = df.groupby('driver_id').apply(maxTrip)
```

The result, for your data sample, is:

```
driver_id
1    4
2    6
dtype: int64
```

Note: It is up to you whether you want to eliminate repeating cities during
one sub-trip (from leaving the stop to return).
I assumed that they are to be eliminated. If you don't want this, drop
`.drop_duplicates()` from my code.

For your data sample this does not matter, since in each sub-trip
city names are unique. But it can happen that a driver visits a city,
then goes to another city and sometimes later (but before the return
to the stop) visits the same city again.

Answer (score 0):

This would be best done using a function. Assuming the name of your dataframe above is df, Consider this as a continuation:

```
drop_cities1 = list(df.loc[1:3, "drop_off_to"]) #Makes a list of all driver 1 drops
pick_cities1 = list(df.loc[1:3, "pickup from"]) #Makes a list of all driver 1 pickups
drop_cities2 = list(df.loc[4:, "drop_off_to"]) 
pick_cities2 = list(df.loc[4:, "pickup from"])
no_of_c1 = 0 #Number of cities visited by driver 1
no_of_c2 = 0 #Number of cities visited by driver 2

def max_trips(pick_list, drop_list):
    no_of_cities = 0
    for pick in pick_list:
        if pick == stop1:
            for drop in drop_list:
            no_of_cities += 1
            if drop == stop1:
                break
    return no_of_cities


max_trips(pick_cities1, drop_cities1)
max_trips(pick_cities2, drop_cities2)
```

Comment: Great, thanks for that, any idea how to make it cater for N number or drivers where N could be 100 driver or so.